# Route IPv6 over OpenVPN IPv4 Tunnel

Tags: routing, openvpn, ipv6

I have accomplished this once before but I cannot find the tutorial that I used or remember how I did it. I have a server that has an IPv6 block assigned to it. I want to create an OpenVPN tunnel from my home router (Running CentOS 6) to the remote server. I then want to assign local lan machines an ip out of that ipv6 block and route ipv6 over the OpenVPN tunnel. I know it is possible because I have done it in the past.  My remote ISP provided an entire /64 last time so I remember splitting it into a /112 and it worked perfectly. Can someone point me to a tutorial or documentation on how to set this up ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excerpt from my `openvpn.conf`, where my hosting provider assigned me `2a01:411:111:222::/64`.

```
server-ipv6 2a01:411:111:222::/64
push tun-ipv6
ifconfig-ipv6 2a01:411:111:222::1 2a01:411:111:222::2
push "route-ipv6 2a01:411:111:222::/64"
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
```

It successfully assigns IPv6 upon client connection and everything seems to be working fine...

Comment: does it allow you to assign addresses to lan computers behind the openvpn connection tho ?